# A continuous function can't take each of its values exactly twice

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Let $h:[0,1]\to \Bbb R$ be a function that takes each of its values exactly twice.
>
> Show that $h$ is not continuous at every point.

Suppose that $h$ is continuous at every point of $[0,1]$. Then $h$ is compact on $[0,1]$ and attains its bounds therein.

Let $h(a_1)=h(a)=\max_{x\in [a,b]} h(x)$, $h(b_1)=h(b)=\min_{x\in [a,b]} h(x)$.

where I take $a<a_1<b_1<b$.

I drew pictures but I could not use the fact that $h$ is continuous to arrive at a contradiction.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Hint: If a function attains its maximum, it needs to attain it twice. Thus, if it is continuous, it needs to "get" to the first maximum, then it needs to go down, then goes back up the the second maximum, and then goes down again. Thus, there are values that are being attained 4 times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the extrema is a good idea.

Let $u=\max h$ and assume $h(a)=h(b)=u$ with $0\le a<b\le 1$.
Pick arbitrary $c$ with $a<c<b$. Note that $h(c)<u$.
If $a>0$, then $h(0)<u$ and we can pick $y$ with $\max\{h(0),h(c)\}<y<u$. By the IVT, there exist $x_1\in(0,a)$, $x_2\in(a,c)$, and $x_3\in (c,b)$ with $h(x_1)=h(x_2)=h(x_3)=y$, contradicting the assumption. Therefore $a=0$.

By a symmetric argument, $b=1$. And the same argument works for the minima, i.e., these must also be attained precisely at $0$ and $1$. This is absurd.

---

It is possible however, that every value is attained either two or three times. Consider $$h(x)=3(2x-1)-(2x-1)^3.$$

Comment: Sir, please can you explain why this is absurd? (Can't constant function attains its supremum and infimum at same points). Please elaborate.